# Angular Service is undefined for no apparent reason

Tags: angular, cordova

I have a DataService component defined which has two methods, one to read from a file using the cordova-file-plugin, the other to write to it.
It used to use the in-mem-web-api, and that worked very fine. I did nothing but change those functions to use the file-API instead.
Now I have a List-component, that does this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.getEntries) ;
    }
```

with

```
getEntries(): void {
    this.dataService.readFromFile(function(fileData) {
        this.entries = fileData;
    });
}
```

Now when ever the component is init'ed or loaded e.g. from a link, the debugger tells me there's a TypeError because `Cannot call method 'readFromFile' of undefined` in `zone.js` - so somehow the service is not defined. However, it is simply injected in the `constructor(private dataService:DataService)` and registered as a provider in app.module, so I am pretty darn clueless why this is happening.

//edit: source of the DataService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Entry } from './entry';

declare var cordova;

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private pathToFile = cordova.file.directory + 'contact-list';

    constructor() { }

    readFromFile(callback) {
    console.log("readFromFile is called");
    (<any> window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.pathToFile, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function() {
            callback(JSON.parse(this.result));
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    }, function ifNoFile
    [...]cut some stuff out here, because it really doesn't matter
        });
        });
    });
    }

    writeToFile(data): void {
    (<any> window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.pathToFile, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
        fileWriter.truncate(0);
        fileWriter.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the source of the DataService

Comment: okay, did so, but: the methods may very well be wrong the way they're written, I just can't get to debugging them, because the actual problem is the DataService is not defined on the Lister-component it's injected into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your event listener callback to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to keep the `this` reference.

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", e => this.getEntries());
```